# Django function not being called

Tags: django, url, view

I have a url conf as follows:

```
url(r'^books/(?{<id>\d+)/personal/$',twobooks.timetable.views.getPersonalizedTimetable),
```

and `getPersonalizedTimeTable` is as follows:

```
def getPersonalizedTimetable(request, id):
        print "AHHH"
        usedTimeSlots = TimeSlot.objects.filter(user = request.user) #All the time slots that hte user has 
        groups = TwobooksGroup.objects.filter(users = request.user)
        print groups
        for group in groups:
            books.append(group.book) 
        slots = []
        for usedTimeSlot in usedTimeSlots:
                slot = {
                        'id': usedTimeSlot.id,
                        'startTime': str(usedTimeSlot.startTime),
                        'endTime': str(usedTimeSlot.endTime),
                    }
                slots.append(slot)

        return render_to_response(
                'books/personal.html',
                {
                        'request': request,
                        'timeslots':slots,
                        'books':books,
                },
                context_instance = RequestContext(request)
        )
```

For some reason the above isn't even being called. `AHHH` is not being printed to terminal and I have no idea why.

Can anyone help?

Comment: szaman is indeed correct about the regex. But what do you mean by when you say that it's not getting called? What page *are* you seeing in your browser? If Django fails to find a matching regex, it will give you a 500 error, and with `Debug=True` in settings.py it will give you all the regexes it tried as well. Is this regex in the base urls.py or in an app? Is that app present in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? Do you have a regex over this one, that could match the URL you are inserting, thus "stealing" the request? :)

Answer (score 4):

Is the url regex correct? I think there shouldn`t be { in it. You can also name parameter which you pass to view

```
url(r'^books/(?P<id>\d+)/personal/$',twobooks.timetable.views.getPersonalizedTimetable),
```

Comment: Hi, I changed that and it's still not printing the 'AHHH' in terminal

Comment: What URL are you using to test it?